# Assigning the Result of a mongodb Find to a Variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I am trying to assign the result of a find in a mongodb to a variable (var user = db.collection("Users").findOne below), but the variable remains undefined. I understand that the find function returns a cursor, but from my understanding, the findOne function is supposed to be different. Would someone know how to assign the result of a find to a variable?

```
     passport.use(
      new LocalStrategy(
      {
       usernameField: "email",
       passwordField: "userName"
      },

     (email, result, done) => {

       var query = {email: email}
       var user = db.collection("Users").findOne((query) => {
         return true
       })

       if (user) {
         done(null, user)
       } else {
         done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username or password'})
       }
     }
   )
 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will always return undefined `findone` needs a callback this is how works

```
var query = {email: email}
       var user = db.collection("Users").findOne(query,(err,user) => {
         if (user) {
         done(null, user)
       } else {
         done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username or password'})
       }
```

Comment: I see. Thank you so much Sven.hig! I have been struggling for hours with this.

Answer (score 0):

You should return from the if/else block and then invoke the function.

I would refactor to something like this using error-first callback pattern after querying db, or try refactoring into an async function which can help with graceful error handling. I think native mongodb connector provides Promise support.

```
     const passport = require("passport");
     const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;


    passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy(
        {
        usernameField: "email",
        passwordField: "userName",
        },
        (email, result, done) => {
        db.collection("Users").findOne({ email: email }, (err, user) => {
            if (err) {
            return done(err);
            }
            if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, {
                message: "Incorrect username or password",
            });
            }
            return done(null, user);
        });
        },
    ),
    );
```